# Python3 + Pygame working in Idle, but not when from Terminal

Tags: macos, python-3.x, pygame

First thanks for taking the time to read this. I'm new to stack overflow, but it seems sweet and I appreciate any time you offer.

I'm currently working with Python3 and Pygame on Mac OS X (10.12.4). I'm using a few resources to get back into Python with some arcade game clones I wanted to make. I had everything working wonderfully through yesterday until I reinstalled OS X. After I had a clean install done on my Mac, I followed instructions to reinstall Xcode, Homebrew, Python3 and Pygame 1.9.4(have also tried 1.9.3), etc. and I'm running into an odd issue I can't seem to find info on. I've researched for a bit here and am hoping someone here can help. Thanks again!

```
$ python3 maze.py
ERROR: pygame.macosx import FAILED
ERROR: pygame.macosx import FAILED
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pygame/macosx.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pygame.pkgdata import getResource
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pygame/pkgdata.py", line 27, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import resource_stream, resource_exists
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1022, in <module>
    class Environment(object):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1025, in Environment
    def __init__(self, search_path=None, platform=get_supported_platform(),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 267, in get_supported_platform
    plat = 'macosx-%s-%s' % ('.'.join(_macosx_vers()[:2]), m.group(3))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 439, in _macosx_vers
    version = platform.mac_ver()[0]
AttributeError: module 'platform' has no attribute 'mac_ver'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "maze.py", line 298, in <module>
    main()
  File "maze.py", line 197, in main
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode([800, 600])
SystemError: <built-in function set_mode> returned a result with an error set
$
```

P.S. I should be able to get back to any answers tonight, or first thing tomorrow.